# when an android app is running in the foreground, how can i enlist the resources used by it?

Tags: android

For example a camera app might use camera, Cpu, memory etc.
Likewise how to get the resource list of the current foreground app

Comment: please make it clear your question?

Comment: Now please check

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you would like to get a list of resources used by that application alone?